# regarding javascript effect

Tags: javascript

http://www.google.co.in/images?um=1&hl=en&biw=1286&bih=707&tbs=isch:1&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&gs_rfai=&q=free%20sports%20car%20vector

goto the above url and place mouse cursor on any image then u can see suddenly image was showing in a div. how generate this type of effect with the help of javascript. please guide.

thanks

Comment: Do you use a JavaScript library?

Comment: `goto` is evil, don't use it, [or else…](http://xkcd.com/292/) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [jQuery TOOLS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html) to achieve similar effect and got good results.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. but onething i just do not understand why someone give me a negative vote for my question. what was wrong in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe someone considered your question not enough specific, or clear, or not helpful to other users. If you choose a more descriptive title or provide a better description of the problem, it would be easier for other users with the same problem to find this question. In addition, people does not like doing other's work and it seems you haven't done any research before posting this question. You don't mention any evaluated alternatives or failed attempts. Good luck!